# Xamarin iOS how to use dSYM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I use Visual Studio on Windows, and always upload my IPA from a MacBook.

I can retreive the dumb files of the iPhone
(Activated from the iPhone: Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > ...)
Then from XCode: Window > Devices > Select device > View Device Logs

When compiling using VS, I guess files are generated in a temporary folder that is deleted later. However compiled files are kept on the Windows computer, in the Bin/Ad-Hoc folder.

My question is: I have all these files, my app is released, I have some crashlogs, how can I desymbolicate them?

Comment: Xamarin links to the following two blog posts that provide info of how to use Xcode's `symbolicatecrash` on your `.app`, `.crash` and `.dSYM` files : Xamarin steps: http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/ Detailed info regarding iOS `.crash` : https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at these!
However what is the .dSYM? a .zip? VS creates a folder named XXX.dSYM containing files (.plist and another big file), should I zip it and copy it to the Mac?

Comment: dSYM files are unique per app and contain the debugging symbols for your app, thus the crash locations can be mapped back your source code locations. Yes copy them over to your Mac (zip, ssh/scp, etc... ) along with the .app and .crash